# Update Vue 2 to Vue 3 with Vite

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs3, vite, vue-composition-api, laravel-10

I'm working on `Vue 2.7` and `Vite 3.2.5` with `Laravel 10`, and I'd like to update Vue to the latest version. I've tried starting with a simple `npm i vue@latest` and it did installed the latest version, but all the dependencies started to collapse. I ended up usin `--force` to update some dependencies and remove others, such as `@vitejs/plugin-vue2`, but I don't feel like using `--force` is a nice thing to do. All this updating almost worked, except for an error, which is happening because I am importing a type inside a Vue component: the error is

> cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sys')

(I'm am using Composition API and Typescript) for a piece of code like this:

```
import { Props } from './Props'
const props = defineProps<Props>()
```

I have searched a bit and I found that I might have to install Typescript as a dependency.

Anyway, if any of you know of some tutorial to update from Vue 2 to Vue 3, using Vite and Laravel, I am very thankful if you share it with me.